# Symplectic Standard map

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I have come across this map, which the notes call *standard symplectic map*.
Why is it symplectic? How do I show it? Are those action-angle variables?

$I(t+1)=I(t)+K\sinθ(t)$

$θ(t+1)=θ(t)+I(t+1) \quad \mod2π$

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which notes?

Comment: My notes, from the lecture :) Should have said “the professor”... my bad

Comment: It would be nice if you could edit this post to put in some physics as I think there is the kernel of a good question there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [symplectic map](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Symplectic_maps) preserves [symplectic structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold), and the simplest example is a map $R^2\rightarrow R^2$ that is area and orientation preserving. [Chirikov's standard map](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Chirikov_standard_map) is the most common example. One can prove that it is area-preserving and hence symplectic by looking at the determinant of the Jacobian: $$|J|=\begin{vmatrix} 
df/dI & df/d\theta \\
dg/dI & dg/d\theta 
\end{vmatrix}
= \begin{vmatrix} 
1 & K\cos(\theta) \\
1 & 1+K\cos(\theta) 
\end{vmatrix}=1(1+K\cos(\theta))-(K\cos(\theta))1=1.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a uick question: why is an area and orientation-preserving map symplectic?

Comment: @DrebinJ. - See the first paragraphs of the first link in my answer.